# C# .rdlc Report Viewer is adding white space on right when printing

Tags: c#, printing, rdlc

I have this issue with a more complex report however I am using a simple line to show the issue at hand. This line spans the entire width of my report when I create it in the designer. I can also export the report through Report Viewer to a pdf and it will span the entire width of the page. However if I attempt and use the print option in report viewer the line will refuse to span the length of the page. I have double checked that no margins are set and that the body of the report is the correct size compared to the report page size. This gap seems to stay a consistent size no matter what I change. It does not seem to be affected by the ConsumeContainerWhiteSpace setting being set to true or false. This is not the same issue as people who are having extra pages of white space being generated. I have tried various page sizes and settings which seem to have no effect on that white space existing.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Seems like this problem happens because of DPI settings imposed by operating system. I was facing the same problem on my Windows 10 and was able to fix it by changing the "DPI Scaling Behavior" in the exe's file properties.

Here is screen shot for your reference:
[image]